# Dijkstra's algorithm concepts

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

I am just learning Dijkstra algorithm and just a little bit confuse in this

```
If min(A,B) = x;
   min(A,C) = y;
   min(B,C) = must be x-y;
```

Please justify it or i am wrong?

Comment: That doesn't look much like [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm) to me.

Comment: And why have you tagged this `java` (including putting the tag back again when @ThreeFx removed it)?

Comment: What you've written is wrong (you've missed assumptions if it is right)

Comment: The ``java`` tag on this question is not justified, since we are not dealing with ``java`` code or ``java``-related concepts. Thank you @NoobEditor

Comment: I can't see how this is related to Dijkstra.

Comment: @Garp it is showing that Dijkstra's actually does what it says it does. I'm writing an answer.

Comment: Dijkstra did much, if `min` means "shortest path" in graph, then `min(B, C) <= x + y` as the path from B to C via A would have a minimal length x + y, and there might be a shorter path. _Tell a bit more._

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought `min` produces the minimum value of either A or B.

Comment: @Garp it means minimum distance, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here's what you meant to say:

I will be referring to a directed non-negative weight graph in all of this.

**The shortest path problem:**

For a digraph G and a node r in V and a real cost vector (c_e:e in E) (I wish we had LaTeX here)

we wish to find:

for each v in V a dipath from r to v of least cost (supposing it exists)

**Here's the gist of what you want:**

suppose we know there's a path from r to v of cost y_v for each v in V, and we find an edge vw in E satisfying y_v + c_vw < y_w

Since appending vw to the dipath to v (to get a path to w) gives a path of length y_v+c_vw

**A least cost dipath satisfies:**

y_v+c_vw >= y_w for all vw in E

We call such a y vector a "feasible potential"

**Proposition: y_v is minimal**

Let y be a feasible potential, and let P be a dipath from r to v, then it follows c(P) >= y_v

Proof:

c(P) = sum c_ei (the the ith edge in the path's cost)

Recall that a feasible potential statisfies y_v + c_vw >= y_w

So c_vw >= y_w - y_v **this is what you have**

Thus

c(P) >= sum (y_vi-y_v{i-1}) (the cost to the ith item take the cost of the previous one)

if you write it as sum (-y_v{i-1} + y_vi) then expand the sum: (y_v0 = 0 obviously)

-y_v0+y_v1 -y_v1 + y_v2 - .... -y_v{k-2} + y_v{k-1} -y_v{k-1} + y_vk

you see all the terms cancel out, giving:

c(P) >= y_vk - y_v0 = y_vk

Thus we have shown c(P) >= y_vk

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong, think about any equilateral triangle, the difference of two sides is 0 and the length of the third size is not.